# Is Souma Yukihara the 9th seat after defeating Akira Hayama?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

I know that the first shokugeki between Souma and Eizan is not for 9th seat but for not Destroying Polar Star Dorm.

There is another shokugeki battle of Souma in Azami Administration Arc vs Akira Hayama.

On Chapter 190 - 191, Souma defeated Hayama. Does it reflect that yukihara now holds 9th seat of elite ten?

Comment: it's probably best that rather saying *"On the previous manga"* you say what chapter you are referring to as what would be the *"previous manga"* one year down the line?

Answer (score 2):

Shokugeki rules elicit that the conditions of winning and losing should be set beforehand. Souma Passes if he wins, gets expelled if he loses. Hayama gets nothing if he wins/loses. Though he had a deal with Azami to be expelled.

**So, No. Souma is NOT a member of Elite 10.**

> In fact  in the next chapter he discusses that if he, Megumi and Aldini, grab the Elite 10 seats. They have a chance of reversing Center's expulsion.

As discussed in the related question,

> Each side must lay out their "compensation", or something they must give up if they were to lose the challenge. Both sides must agree that the compensation of the duel equate with each other.

Source: [Wiki: Shokugeki](http://shokugekinosoma.wikia.com/wiki/Shokugeki)

This is established pretty early when Souma challenges Isshiki for his 7th seat earlier!